# The Drop() method appears to do nothing to my dataframe, but no error is given

Tags: python, pandas

I am using drop() to try to remove a row from a dataframe, based on an index. Nothing seems to happen. I get lots of errors if I play with the syntax, but the below example yields the same dataframe I started with.

```
data= {"col1":[1, 3, 3,3],"col2":[4,5,6,4],"col3":[7,6,6,8]}
testdf2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

testdf2.drop([1])
testdf2
```

I assume I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: try `newDF = testdf2.drop([1])`

Comment: most of actions have no effect, just visuals, you must assign it to the new DF or the same DF or, use `inplace=True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using drop, you must reassign to your df (Or create a new one).

```py
import pandas as pd
data= {"col1":[1, 3, 3,3],"col2":[4,5,6,4],"col3":[7,6,6,8]}
testdf2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

testdf2 = testdf2.drop([1])
testdf2
```

Alternatively, supply inplace.

```py
testdf2.drop([1], inplace=True)
```

However, this could lead to complications regarding view / copy and I usually reassign.

Hope that helps!